# Tmux is not running under a terminal?

Tags: process, tmux

I starts to use `tmux` and find an interesting thing,

In the `gnome-terminal`

```
$ pstree -asp $$
systemd,1 splash
  └─systemd,14385 --user
      └─gnome-terminal-,15157
          └─bash,17525
              └─pstree,17551 -asp 17525
```

It is clear that the current `pstree -asp $$` running under `gnome-terminal`

However, when launched tmux

```
$ pstree -asp $$
systemd,1 splash
  └─systemd,14385 --user
      └─tmux: server,16469
          └─bash,17699
              └─pstree,17794 -asp 17699
```

Why tmux is not under `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: Because gnome terminal is a GUI application which depends on logged in session. Whole point of tmux is to have a shell  session running detached from terminal application. This is how tmux can be started on a remote server, then have say minecraft server running inside tmux, and then you can detach and still have that server running ( without having to keep terminal open on local machine ). Very very useful, and I use that all the time in my tasks

Comment: amazing, I heavily depended on `nohup`, could you please transmit the comment to answer @SergiyKolodyazhnyy

Comment: I am using phone at the moment so I will have to post a proper answer later when I am at my workstation, with examples attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big difference is that `gnome-terminal` is a GUI application, a window. It's a sort of interface to the shell, but they're essentially separate. When GUI application exits, the GUI server ( X11 and presumably Wayland as well ) cleans up the windows and closes them. `gnome-terminal` being a parent of the shell, will send a SIGHUP to close the child processes, and that will close the shell session. Similar situation occurs with TTY consoles or ssh. In TTY, you have `agetty` process, which will accept your login credentials and then launch a particular program, typically a shell, though in certain cases it could be configured to run something else entirely.

Now, `tmux` is different - it is a console application and doesn't depend on login (though you could [make it appear upon login to tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335703/85039)). Say you've got a server in New York, but you are in California. You want to start a long running command, maybe upgrade, and disconnect from the remote session. What you can do is start `tmux`, start the command in the  shell `tmux` opens, and via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> & <kbd>d</kbd> detach from the session. The command will remain running in the shell instance managed by `tmux` unlike `gnome-terminal`. Next day you can do

```
$ tmux ls
0: 1 windows (created Fri May 17 13:42:54 2019) [167x48]
```

to find the running sessions and connect back to it via

```
$ tmux attach
```

for the most recent session or via

```
$ tmux attach -t 0
```

to attach to the session named 0 as in my example. Overall `tmux` has server-client approach, where you connect to the a particular session handled by the server process, and that communication goes on via a unix domain socket ( by default in `/tmp/tmux-<UID>` ), so long as the system hasn't been rebooted.

Underneath the hood, both `tmux` and `gnome-terminal` use `pts` virtual terminal device (unlike `tty` which is used for serial consoles or the virtual tty1 console for example). They both are capable of launching interactive shell and individual commands from `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, or something you custom built. Yet their essential purpose is  different.

See also

- [Difference between pts and tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21280/85039)